# Run a flask app within AWS Sagemaker using a custom model

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I've searched for solutions at AWS and Stackoverflow but haven't got a satisfying answer. I have a Sagemaker notebook instance where I built a custom model (not sklearn/tf/torch) which would calculated a result csv file and save it in the notebook.

Now I need to serve predictions using the csv file. The input is id and output is the pre-calculated result from the csv. The sagemaker "deploy custom model" examples only include sklearn/tf/torch models.

Is there a way to create an model endpoint serving pre-calculated predictions from csv files?

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of `bring your own (BYO)` theme in sagemaker, Here's the git [link](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/advanced_functionality) for different use cases. Choose one among them which is close to your use case. In the predictor.py file, you can directly fetch the pre-calculated results from s3 and serve them using the endpoint.

Comment: This recommendation does not directly address the question being asked.